# Probably wrong use of memory-Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When the 1st value I've assigned to the integer "number" gets assigned to the R array, my program crashes. It probably has something to do with the pointer I've created and I do not seem to be able to find what is the problem. If I omit this part of the code:

```
else{
    while (k<=n/2){
        temp2=R[k];
        R[l-1]=temp2;
        R[k]=R[l-1];}
        l-=1;
        k+=1;
    }
```

, the program runs fine, even though it gives a different output. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int i,n,number,temp,j,k=0,l,temp2;
    int *R;

    R=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    printf("Dwse mou to megethos tou pinaka se parakalw poly:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("Dwse enan thetiko akeraio arithmo:\n");
            scanf("%d", &number);
            R[i]=number;
    }
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        temp=R[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((temp>R[j])&&(j>=0)){
            R[j+1]=R[j];
            j=j-1;
      }
        R[j+1]=temp;
  }
    l=n;
    if (n%2==0)
        printf("Einai adynato na ginei h taksinomhsh:\n");
    else{
        while (k<=n/2){
            temp2=R[k];
            R[l-1]=temp2;
            R[k]=R[l-1];}
            l-=1;
            k+=1;
        }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("R[%d]: %d\n", i, R[i]);
        }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `R=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` move to after `scanf("%d", &n);`.

Comment: you are allocating the array R using the variable `n` which is not initialized

Comment: Well, thank you very much and pardon me for making such kind of questions due to my noobishness.

Comment: Also else-block is wrong.

Comment: What's not right?

Comment: 1) `temp2=R[k];
            R[l-1]=temp2;
            R[k]=R[l-1];`  Probably You want swap. but It didn't correctly it. 2) `while (k<=n/2){...}` : `k` don't update in while-body.

Comment: Oh, true. Wrong use of brackets. Hadn't checked the code till the end after you answered my question. The program does exactly what I wanted it to do now, thanks to your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i,n,number,temp,j,k=0,l,temp2;
int *R;

R=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

What value does `n` have? It's uninitialized, so you invoke *undefined behavior* in C lingo. Anything may happen, and a crash is one thing.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem indeed.

Comment: @Achilles Wonderful. The next step on Stack Overflow is to *accept* the answer that helped you most by clicking the green check mark to the left. This will earn you a few points of credit.